# Scala regex pattern extractor

Tags: regex, scala

What am I doing wrong here:

```scala
val pattern = "([1-7]),([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])".r
val pattern(count, fruit) = "7,2323"
```

gives:

```
[info]   Scenario: For a set of combination of hour formats, map them to the expected 24 hours format1 *** FAILED ***
[info]   scala.MatchError: 7,2323 (of class java.lang.String)
[info]   at com.mf.location.os.service.util.HoursFormatUtil$.fromHours(HoursFormatUtil.scala:55)
[info]   at com.mf.location.os.service.util.HoursFormatUtilSpec.$anonfun$new$9(HoursFormatUtilSpec.scala:71)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
[info]   at org.scalatest.featurespec.AnyFeatureSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(AnyFeatureSpecLike.scala:257)
[info]   at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
[info]   at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
```

However `println(s"matches ${pattern.matches("7,2323")}")` returns true.

Comment: What is count and what is fruit here?

Answer (score 4):

If your `count` value should be `7` and the `fruit` value should be `2323`, you can use

```scala
val pattern = "([1-7]),((?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]){2})".r
val line = "7,2323"
val (count, fruit) = line match {
  case pattern(count, fruit) => (count,fruit)
  case _ => ("","")
}
println(s"${count} and ${fruit}")
// => 7 and 2323
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/ZGEFO34209).

Note the `([1-7]),((?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]){2})` refactored pattern that now contains only two capturing groups. `pattern(count, fruit)` "extracts" the capturing group values and assigns them to `count` and `fruit`. If there is no match, these variable will be empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on top of the great answer by @Wiktor, please note that in your regex, you expect 3 capturing groups, while you are trying to assign them into 2 variables. This is the reason you get a matching error.

```scala
"([1-7]),([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])".r
 ↑     ↑ ↑                    ↑↑                   ↑
 group 1      group 2                 group 3
```

If for example you try to do:

```scala
val pattern = "([1-7]),([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3])".r
val pattern(count, fruit, other) = "7,2323"
println(s"count: $count fruit: $fruit other: $other")
```

The output is:

```scala
count: 7 fruit: 23 other: 23
```

However, when you later on do `pattern.matches("7,2323")` you get true, because there is a match. You just don't capture it by the correct groups amount.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KAZzLzQlTimOT2EkFaa0Hw).

Comment: The reason I went with `match` block is because an exception will be thrown if there is no match, try your code with a non-matching string like `val pattern(count, fruit, other) = "7,233"`.

Comment: I know @WiktorStribiżew. I completely understand your answer and upvoted it. I tried to explain why there was no match and to show how this can be done in the OPs approach. If I had to choose one of our two solutions I'd choose yours.